# Redirect non-existent page or directory to existing parent page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My site is static and has file extensions in the url like "`.html`". In case someone enters the following URLs (which do not exist), I would want to redirect them from:

```
example.com/state/city
example.com/state/city/
```

to:

```
example.com/state/city.html
```

I have done it using an `index.html` page in the `/city` folder:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content="1; url=../city.html" />
<script>window.location.href="../city.html"</script>
</head>
</html>
```

But I would want to use `.htaccess` to do it, and I want to use regular expression `(.*)` so that these could also be used for other directories. I tried this but it does not seem to work correctly. I would also like to exclude the homepage `example.com` from being redirected:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ $1.html [R=302,NC,L]
```

Comment: When configured in .htaccess, the URL path the RewriteRule matches against, never starts with a slash.

Comment: @CBroe, Thanks for the info. I have edited the code, but the browser shows an error that says the page redirected too many times. How can this be fixed?